# Bootstrap 4 tooltip position issue

Tags: jquery, reactjs, bootstrap-4, tooltip, popper.js

Bootstrap 4 Tooltip is not displaying where its suppose to in a reactjs application.

I have tried everything like

- setting `container: body`
- setting body style to `position: relative;`

My code has following hierarchy in html head

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/bootstrap-4.1.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/popper-1.12.9.min.js" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/bootstrap-4.1.min.js" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/script.js" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/react-widgets.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/styles.css" />
```

Usage:

```
<div data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" data-original-title="Title Here">
    <a>Links Goes Here</a>
</div>
```

Here is a screenshot

https://i.ibb.co/kDzjL7c/CADS.png

Comment: your parent element doing this check it again or provide code so we will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Move your attributes inside `a` tag like this:

```
<div>
  <h3>Tooltip Example</h3>
  <a data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" data-original-title="Title Here">Hover over me</a>
</div>
```